# Generalize an equation for $y_i$ given the following sequence of functions: $y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1$, . . .

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Generalize an equation for $y_i$ given the following sequence of functions:

$$ \begin{align} 
y_1 &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 \\
y_2 &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2 \\
y_3 &= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2 + \beta_4x_3 + \beta_5x_1x_3 + \beta_6x_2x_3 + \beta_7x_1x_2x_3 \\
&\vdots \\
y_n &= \textrm{ ? } \\
&\vdots \\
\end{align} $$

–——–——–——–——–——–——

In my efforts to find a solution, I noticed that if you ignore the beta coefficients, then the remaining variables can be written as such:

$$
y_i^* = \prod_i(x_i + 1) = 1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_1x_2 + x_3 + x_1x_3 + x_2x_3 + x_1x_2x_3 + \dots
$$

Also, consider the case of $i = 3$ (for example). We see that...

$$ \begin{align} 
    y_3 & = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2 + \beta_4x_3 + \beta_5x_1x_3 + \beta_6x_2x_3 + \beta_7x_1x_2x_3 
\\ & 
    = \begin{bmatrix}
    \beta_0 \\
    \beta_1 \\
    \beta_2 \\
    \beta_3 \\
    \beta_4 \\
    \beta_5 \\
    \beta_6 \\
    \beta_7 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & x_1 & x_2 & x_1x_2 & x_3 & x_1x_3 & x_2x_3 & x_1x_2x_3
    \end{bmatrix}
\\ 
\end{align} $$

And...

$$
y_3^* = \prod_{i=1}^{3}(x_i + 1) = \tau_0 + \tau_1 + \tau_2 + \tau_3 + \tau_4 + \tau_5 + \tau_6 + \tau_7 \textrm{, where...}
$$
$$ \begin{align} 
&
\tau_0 = 1
\\ &
\tau_1 = x_1
\\ &
\tau_2 = x_2
\\ &
\tau_3 = x_1x_2
\\ &
\tau_4 = x_3
\\ &
\tau_5 = x_1x_3
\\ &
\tau_6 = x_2x_3
\\ &
\tau_7 = x_1x_2x_3
\\ &
\end{align} $$

So, if there is a way to extract the respective $\tau_i$ terms from $y_i^*$, then we could write $y_i$ as...

$$
y_i = \sum_i\beta_i\tau_i
$$

Therefore, generalizing an equation for $\tau_i$ would trivially help generalize an equation for $y_i$. However, it's not clear to me how to go about extracting $\tau_i$ from $y_i^*$.

This may (or may not) be a step the right direction. Thank you for your help in advanced.

Comment: Are you missing an $x_2x_3$ term, or is it correct as written?

Comment: @BobJones, I was missing an $x_2x_3$ term. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One formula is $\displaystyle\sum_{S\subseteq\{1, 2, \ldots n\}}\beta_{\sum_{i\in S}2^{i-1}}\prod_{i\in S}x_i$. The index of $\beta$ is just the sum of $2^{i-1}$ for $i$ being the subscripts of the $x$'s in the term.